# Assigned To field not showing user with the same name as a deleted user

Tags: tfs

We had a person leave our company and their windows domain account for Active Directory was deleted.  They have since come back but have been given a different windows domain account user name.  Now when we attempt to assign them tasks it's always associated with the old account.  I assume this is because the name is still the same and TFS is doing some kind of duplication check.  I've tried removing cache and have verified that the **Team Foundation Server Periodic Identity Synchronization** job is running properly.  I can also see the old active directory account show up when attempting to **Add a windows user or group** via the dialog along with the new Active Directory user.

What's strange is this user is not showing up as a member of any groups in TFS for any of the Team Project Collections. So why are they still showing up in the **[Team Project Collection]\Project Collection Valid Users** group?

Comment: What's the rule of assigned to field now, `VALIDUSER`, `ALLOWEDVALUES`, `ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE`?

Comment: Did you mean the user using the new domain account  are using the same name with the *"old delete user" (old domain account)* ? Could you see the "old delete user" (old domain account) still in TFS server?

Comment: So the user's new domain account has the same full name as his deleted windows domain account.  We've removed his access from the Team Project and only gave access to his new AD account.  Every time we assign a task to his name it is associated with the old AD account and not his new one.  There aren't multiple options in the Assigned To select list with his name duplicated.  So I assume TFS is doing some type of distinct on full name from AD that is preventing his new account from being associated.  i.e. username was t\t_name now is t\test_name but his full name in AD is showing as User, Test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the main issue is deleted users still in "Assigned To" List. First try to throw down the issue.

If you are using `VALIDUSER` rule, it contains all valid users in TFS. You may check collection level Project Collection Valid Users group, you may need to check every group to delete the user. And use `TFSSecurity /imx` command to display information about that group, thn delete the user from right group.

After delete the old user, you need to try to let TFS sync with Active Directory, for detail steps, you can refer to:

- [Force TFS to sync with Active Directory](http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/)
- [Active Directory Groups not Syncing with Team Foundation Server 2010](https://nkdagility.com/active-directory-groups-not-syncing-with-team-foundation-server-2010/)

Comment: So I see this user's old windows domain account is in a [Team Project Collection]\Project Collection Valid Users group.

Comment: What's strange is this user is not showing up as a member of any groups in TFS for any of the Team Project Collections.  So why are they still showing up in the **[Team Project Collection]\Project Collection Valid Users group**?

Comment: There are many possibilities, seems you didn't remove the old user from TFS completely. Try to user tfs secruity /a- command(https://www.visualstudio.com/zh-cn/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd) to remove the user from TFS again. Then do the force sync as mentioned above.  Make sure you will not see the old user account in TFS. Then try the assign to again.

Comment: So doing this work related to what you provided seems to have done the trick.  I now at least see the new account as an option in the Assigned To field.